# How to avoid recursive loops when using data binding in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

As somewhat contrived example consider a simple FX calculator having amounts in two different currencies and a rate to covert between them. The rules are then when either amount is changed the rate is calculates and if the rate is changed then the second amount is calculated from the first amount and the exchange rate.

With the implementation below which has all the interaction logic in the view model, changing any amount in the GUI results in a mutually recursive loop.

One way to attempt to fix it would be be to add checks on setter for the model so that an event is  not raised when setting a property to its existing value which is in any case good practice. However this is not a foolproof solution in itself as with floating point numbers there is always the possibility that there is a small rounding error which results in an event being raised.

In a world without data binding updates to the model and other text boxes could be done in the LostFocus event of the text box that changed which would not trigger any further event as we only responding to user events not changes in the data.

Another way I thought of would be to have flags to indicate a certain field is being updated programmatically  and ignore changes to that field when the flag is set but that soon becomes messy when a lot of fields are involved.

Are there are any standard techniques or patterns which are used to address this issue in WPF apps?

The view model

```
namespace LoopingUpdates
{
    public class FxModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _amountCcy1;
        private double _amountCcy2;
        private double _rate;

        public double AmountCcy1
        {
            get { return _amountCcy1;  }
            set
            {
                _amountCcy1 = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AmountCcy1"));
            }
        }

        public double AmountCcy2
        {
            get { return _amountCcy2; }
            set
            {
                _amountCcy2 = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AmountCcy2"));
            }
        }

        public double Rate
        {
            get { return _rate; }
            set
            {
                _rate = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Rate"));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public FxModel FxModel { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            FxModel = new FxModel() { AmountCcy1 = 100, AmountCcy2 = 200, Rate = 2 };
            FxModel.PropertyChanged += FxModel_PropertyChanged;
        }

        private void FxModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.PropertyName) {
                case "AmountCcy1":
                    Debug.WriteLine("Amount Ccy 1 changed");
                    FxModel.Rate = FxModel.AmountCcy2 / FxModel.AmountCcy1;
                    break;

                case "AmountCcy2":
                    Debug.WriteLine("Amount Ccy 2 changed");
                    FxModel.Rate = FxModel.AmountCcy2 / FxModel.AmountCcy1;
                    break;

                case "Rate":
                    Debug.WriteLine("Rate 1 changed");
                    FxModel.AmountCcy2 = FxModel.AmountCcy1 * FxModel.Rate;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The window xaml

```
<Window x:Class="LoopingUpdates.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoopingUpdates"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="148.7" Width="255.556" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Amount Ccy 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Amount Ccy 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="label2" Content="Rate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAmountCcy1" Text="{Binding FxModel.AmountCcy1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="99,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAmountCcy2" Text="{Binding FxModel.AmountCcy2}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="99,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72"  />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtRate" Text="{Binding FxModel.Rate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="99,72,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The window code behind

```
namespace LoopingUpdates
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're worried about rounding errors, then use a Boolean flag in the setters. For what you're doing here, you do not need a separate flag for each property, only a single class-wide flag that is shared by all of the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

I see two ways to face that problem:

1. Create a Property `IsUpdating` and do not handle `PropertyChanged` if the `IsUpdating` is true. Then you can "deactivate" updating process...
2. Create a second property for each one (e.g. `RateInternal`, `AmountCcy2Internal`, ...) that doesn't call property changed.

These options are not ideal, but I don't know a better way.

Comment: I ended up doing something like the first option, while it requires adding lots of checks i'ts robust and simple.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with putting a check in your property setter such as

```
if (property == value)
    return;
```

And therefore not setting the property or raising the property changed event.  If rounding is what you're afraid of then I would take care of the rounding in the ViewModel also.

Answer (score 1):

I always avoid recursive loops checking if `(value != _privateField)` inside the setters of my ViewModel's properties.

If you think rounding may be a problem, I would just change the values of the fields and call `PropertyChanged` if the **rounded** values are different:

```
public double AmountCcy1
{
    get { return _amountCcy1; }
    set
    {
        if (Math.Round(value, 2) != Math.Round(_amountCcy1, 2))
        {
            _amountCcy1 = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AmountCcy1"));
        }
    }
}

public double AmountCcy2
{
    get { return _amountCcy2; }
    set
    {
        if (Math.Round(value, 2) != Math.Round(_amountCcy2, 2))
        {
            _amountCcy2 = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AmountCcy2"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I'm not sure that rounding completely solves the issue. You could get a situation where the old value is 2.4999... and the new number is 2.5000... The  difference is tiny but its enough to make the two numbers round to different values. I've seen funny stuff like this happen with floating point numbers. Also you are relying on the fact that logic will calculate the same number as the original update, although I can't think of a situation where that wouldn't be a bug.